# Spring Boot Integration with Azure AD BC

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am building spring boot application which will use Azure AD , right now don't have UI so I want to create Services using REST API

1. New User Sign Up
2. New User Sign In
   3)Edit profile
   4)Updated role for User

I don't find much documentation around this , Can i connect my Application running on my local to AD?

These Services i want to testing POSTMAN or SOAP UI.

Regards,
Devendra

Answer (score 0):

Using Azure AD B2C you can create user flows/Custom policy for the [New user sign-up/ Sign-in / Edit Profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows), using this you can also [test the user flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows).

Please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory-b2c-oidc) on how to build Spring Boot Starter for Azure Active Directory B2C and there are some [GitHub samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/spring/azure-spring-boot-samples) which can be helpful for you.
w.r.t [user management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/manage-user-accounts-graph-api#user-management-microsoft-graph-operations) operations you need to connect with microsoft graph API using the access token.